# Enviar comprobantes a sunat Usando c# mvc net core 6

Tags: c#, webservice, asp.net-core, soap

Estoy utilizando c# mvc net core 6, para el envió de comprobantes electrónicos a sunat, pero recibo la excepcion: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException al recibir la respuesta al servicio soap. Alguna solución para evitar recibir esta excepción.

```
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new 
        BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential); 
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None; 
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None; 
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = 
        BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName; binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = 
        System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;

        //PARA SERVICIO PRODUCCION SUNAT
        EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://e-factura.sunat.gob.pe/ol-ti-itcpfegem/billService");
        billServiceClient servicio = new billServiceClient(binding, remoteAddress);


        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
        servicio.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "usuario";
        servicio.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";

        await servicio.OpenAsync();

        sendBillResponse response = await servicio.sendBillAsync(Path.GetFileName(zipFilePath), bitArray, "0");
        byte[] returnByte = response.applicationResponse;

        await servicio.CloseAsync();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, pone el mensaje de error completo para saber a que se esta refiriendo

Comment: Prueba usando `HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm` en `binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType`

Comment: Sigo recibiendo la excepción System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'El procesador de seguridad no encontró un encabezado de seguridad en el mensaje. La causa puede ser que el mensaje sea un error no protegido o que no coincidan los enlaces entre las partes de la comunicación. Esto puede suceder si el servicio está configurado para seguridad y el cliente no usa seguridad.'